# Opening file in TextEdit to a specific line using command line?

Tags: command-line, textedit

How do I open a file in TextEdit to the beginning of a specific line (specified by line number), using the command line?

Comment: What do you mean by "to a line"? Do you mean with the cursor on that line? TBH, for any serious text editing, I'd use BBEdit or other app.

Comment: @benwiggy I meant to the beginning of a specific line, by line number

Comment: You probably can use UI Scripting and send keystrokes to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, but you'd need to know how many Page Downs you would need to implement for a given file, within the script. You might as well just tap the button yourself.

Comment: Note that TextEdit has a `go to line` function (command+L)

Comment: @benwiggy "Cursor down" should go line by line. But Cmd-L is even easier.

Comment: Well, so it does! I still say the answer to most questions with TextEdit is: "Use BBEdit".